# Ошибка в разделе "Достижение"

Tags: поддержка

Я тут новичок только месяц, и вчера было странное отображение информации, объясните пожалуйста или ссылку где почитать.

Вчера был на сайте и как-будто у меня приняли правильный ответ,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доступ к привилегии открывается с рейтинга 500, у меня на скрине 512, перехожу на страницу профиля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

От чего такое странное поведение? Галочка стоит показывать удаленные сообщения

Проверил репутацию, нашел вот такой интересный момент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

перешел на данный вопрос, минусов нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, а второго ответа нет, так что ваш ответ не мог быть не принятым, разве что другой ответ(ы) могли удалить.

Comment: Нет, я тут ничего не удалял - точно. А может такое быть, что человек случайно нажал минус а потом плюс? И в результате такое вывелось в рейтинге?

Comment: Наверное так оно и есть, ну более опытные пользователи будут знать, тут я не особо знаток.

Comment: Может более знающие ответят, но все равно спасибо за уделенное время

Comment: @ΝNL993, так галочку можно и снять, не только поставить.

Comment: @Александр, скорее нажал плюс, а потом отменил. При смене с минуса на плюс будет +12 и результат явно станет больше, а не меньше.

Comment: ну ладно, может и так, спасибо. А почему это вчера проявилось если этот минус - плюс был 2 дня назад?